# NFS: too many levels of symbolic links. How to find and fix?

Tags: filesystems, symbolic-link, nfs

```
wim@wim-desktop:/media/data/dots/manouche$ ls > /dev/null
ls: reading directory .: Too many levels of symbolic links
wim@wim-desktop:/media/data/dots/manouche$ find . -type l -exec ls -l {} \;
wim@wim-desktop:/media/data/dots/manouche$ ls -lR . | grep ^l
ls: reading directory .: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I have this problem on my filesystem, and googling suggests there is a circular symbolic link somewhere.  But I can't find it, the commands I'm trying to recursively look for links aren't returning any results.

Comment: Try `ls -ld`, where `-d` tells to _list directory entries instead of contents, and do not  dereference symbolic links_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the usual "circular link" error (that's why `find` doesn't help you). It says,

```
ls: **reading directory .**: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

So the error "Too many levels of symbolic links" is occurring *while reading the current directory*. It looks like a serious bug in either the driver or the physical filesystem; I'd try unmounting and fscking.

The error is caught in `print_dir()` inside the source of `ls` coreutil:

```
  else if (errno != 0)
  {
      file_failure (command_line_arg, _("reading directory %s"), name);
      if (errno != EOVERFLOW)
        break;
  }
```

and is caused by `readdir` returning `ELOOP`. It seems to be [a bug concerning NFS](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6161) which should leave traces in your dmesg (`dmesg | tail`). File system and OS version seem relevant; what are yours?

Comment: It's NFS on a synology NAS, the share is mounted in Ubuntu 13.04.  Last line of dmesg was `[75632.751021] NFS: directory dots/manouche contains a readdir loop.Please contact your server vendor.  The file: ARPEGEDIATONIQUEG7.pdf has duplicate cookie 812789874`

Comment: As I feared. The problem is not in the filesystem, it is in the NFS layer of the Synology (see http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=61474). You'll have to switch to CIFS/Samba if possible, or query Synology for a 'firmware' update. There are a couple of hacks described here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nfs-stale-file-handle-error-and-solution.html .

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm trying a firmware upgrade to DSM-4.2-3211 (was on 4.1-2636)